# objective-c extract single value from json string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json

I have the following json returned string:

```
[{"status":2,"id":"-1","content":"User has entered wrong input","time":1346765646202}]
```

(as you can see the result is in an array that contains a single object).

How can I extract the value of status and content without Enumeration?

For now I created a dictionary and run on it with enumeration, but I don't like the solution:

```
NSData *jsonData = [returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the whole thing is wrapped in [], it will deserialize into an NSArray (of size 1) (not an NSDictionary as your code implies). The element in that array will be an NSDictionary (`{}`). You can get that dictionary with `objectAtIndex:0` and skip your enumeration:

```
NSData *jsonData = [returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
NSDictionary *response = [json objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *status = [response objectForKey:@"status"];
NSString *content = [response objectForKey:@"content"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber * status = json[@"status"]
```

or

```
NSNumber * status = [json objectForKey: @"status"]
```

etc.

Comment: NSNumber *status = [json objectForKey: @"status"]; throws an exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: please note that it's an array of json strings